# How to prevent data duplicacy in Django many-to-many relation?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a table Verticals, and I have a table Sources.
There is another table Sources_Verticals which maps the many-to-many relationship of both table elements.

[Image of Database Sources_verticlas table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytJ11.png)

This table shows the mapping.
The table should not allow duplicacy of data like it has done it in:
Paytm : Ecommerce, Hotel, Travel
Paytm : Ecommerce, Travel

Either it should not give option to map the pre-mapped elements under Paytm, or it should merge Hotel into previously existing record.

Comment: which table field you dont want duplicate set is primary key too. Or query that field before save the table, if already exists dont save again.

Comment: Let me get a bit clear over here.

1:::I select option paytm for the first time, i should get options for Ecommerce, Hotel, travel.

2::: Suppose i select Ecommerce and Hotel and save

3::: Now  if i select Paytm for the second time, I should get option only for travel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you need something like this. This may not be good solution but it will do what you need:

```
Verticals Sources            Sources_Verticals
--------- -------            -----------------
Paymt     Ecommerce          Paymt  - Ecommerce, Hotel
          Hotel              Paymt  - Travel
          Travel

# query Paymt to get id
vertical = Verticals.objects.get(vertical_name='Paymt')

# use Paymt id to get all record in Sources_Verticals table which related with Paymt
source_ver = Sources_Verticals.objects.get(vertical_id=vertical.id)

# all sources
sources = Sources.objects.all()

# iterate over sources to
for source in sources:
    # check which source not in the list
    if source.id not in source_ver:
        # save this source with Paymt
        s = Sources_Verticals(vertical_id=vertical.id, source_id=source.id)
        s.save()
```

Comment: It should be for all sources, not just **paytm** . **Paytm** was just an example.

Comment: yes I know. Just I show you how to do. Lets say you have `source_id` and `vertical_id` in `Sources_Verticals` model, if you want to check all `Verticals`, you should `join` `Sources_Verticals` and `Verticals` model and get all Verticals which on both model then you can check for every vertical.